# Feynman Diagram Issues

Tags: feynmf

First time posting questions on this specific forum. I am trying to draw a Feynman diagram for the process in which a fermion-antifermion pair annihilate at vertex v1 and a fermion-antifermion pair is created a vertex v2 through an instantaneous Coulomb interaction, using the package feynmf. However, when I use the following

```
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,80)
    \fmftop{o1,o2}
    \fmfbottom{i1,i2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{o1,v2,i2}
    \fmf{ghost}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
```

the vertical line for the Coulomb doesn't show up.

[image: feynmf]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: What is the minimal compilable code of your work?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{ghost}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,80)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2,i2}
\fmf{ghost}{v1,v2}
\fmfdot{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Version of  the user @Thruston** `\fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}` instead of `\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2,i2}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{ghost}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,80)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
\fmf{ghost}{v1,v2}
\fmfdot{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** without the dots.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{ghost}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,80)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
\fmf{ghost}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I actually need the diagram I posted above, but with the left and right parts separated by a vertical dashed line.

Comment: then change `\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2,i2}` to `\fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}`...